# minimum size for terraform aurora "aws_db_instance"

Tags: terraform, amazon-aurora

Im trying to put together some terraform samples for rds. Hoping to create a single instance aurora with smallest footprint.

For

```
engine = "aurora" 
instance_class = "db.t3.small"
```

I can't seem to find a value for `allocated_storage` that terraform will accept.

Every attempt gives me: `Error creating DB Instance: InvalidParameterCombination: Invalid storage size for engine name aurora-mysql and storage type aurora:`

Comment: Can you post the Terraform code? As far as I can see, `aws_rds_cluster` does not have an argument for the instance class. However, the `aws_rds_cluster_instance` resource does have both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't allocate a fixed storage size for Aurora. [Storage size in Aurora is automatically allocated](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Aurora.Overview.StorageReliability.html#aurora-storage-growth).

Comment: If I leave off the 'allocated_storage' i get this msg: `│ Error: provider.aws: aws_db_instance: aurora_default_db: "allocated_storage": required field is not set`

Comment: Aurora instances are created via the Terraform `aws_rds_cluster_instance` resource, not the `aws_db_instance` resource.

Comment: So there has to be a cluster - no solo instances?

Comment: Aurora only operates in cluster mode. It can be a cluster of 1 instance, but it is still a cluster, with data spread across 3 availability zones. That's a fundamental feature of Aurora.